# Auto Indentation not working in Code-blocks 13.12 (svn 9636)

Tags: 12.04, code-blocks

I am using 12.04 LTS and for that reason I am not being able to install the latest packages of code-blocks 13.12 directly which we get directly from [code-blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries) website. So, I had to use the alternative and get it from [here](https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ppa/). The installation went perfectly and code-blocks runs perfectly. But with a small defect. It doesn't Auto indent.

If I press `{`, then a structure like this is expected.

```
{
    //code here
}
```

But this is not happening. What I should do? Auto indent is necessary for me. I confirm I have checked `Settings->Editor->General Setting->Auto indent`, and it is properly checked. So, the auto indent feature is in activated form.

Answer (score 4):

Install contrib plugin by:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib
```